# マイグレーションの実行がうまくいきません。laravel5.6を使っています。

Tags: mysql, laravel

マイグレーションの実行がうまくいきません。laravel5.6を使っています。
下記の第一回目のスライド66を行っています。
https://schoo.jp/class/3651#

実行結果

```
php artisan migrate
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample</title>
<style>
body { color:gray; }
h1 { font-size:18pt; font-weight:bold; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
debu22 <h1>Sample</h1>
<p>dai</p>
</body>

[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'daikunn-mygle' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = mygle and table_name = migration
s)



[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'mygle'
```

下記を実行したいのにmygleがないという情報が出てしまいます。
これは前に自分で作ったマイグレーションのようですがそれを削除しないとうまくいかないのでしょうか？
2017_12_11_101415_create_tweet_table.php

phpmyadminで行っても恐らく同じだと思うので、こちらで作っても構いませんので初心者にわかるように教えていただければ幸いです。

本当はlaravelの初心者用の本でもあると良いのですが新しいせいか初心者用の本がまだないようです。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/105853

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11183213601

Comment: ヘルプやMETAも見た方がいいと思います。まずはこちらの [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2418/])をご覧ください。当サイト以外で質問者が解決済みかどうか判断するためにマルチポスト先は記載します。記載がない場合は他の方がフォローのために記載しているだけなので気にすることはありません。

Comment: 良い回答をいただけなかったため一度終了したいのですがどのようにＢＡを選ばずに終了するのでしょうか？

Comment: 参考にしてください https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2634/

Comment: ありがとうございます。匿名化の依頼をしました。

Comment: @nicomesecond 「質問の匿名化」は、実のところわりと特殊なオペレーションで、ボタンひとつで即実行、というわけにはいきません。今回のケースでは、「質問の削除」は(可能不可能かで言えば)可能だと認識しています。通常のオペレーションである「質問の削除」を実施できない特別な理由などありますでしょうか?

Comment: user26766という方が悪い回答をしてしまったので、削除ができないのです。

Answer (score -2):

schooを見ないとわからない質問はschooの中でしたほうが良いと思います。
そういった教材は基本的に言われた通りやればできるようになっているので、どこかで手順を間違えているのではないでしょうか。

DBがないと言われたのならば、DBを作る手順を抜かしているのだとおもいます。もう一度教材を見てみることをオススメします。

Comment: そうは思いません。バージョンや環境の差異によって起こる問題はありますし、質問者が利用しているバージョンは開発版のもので安定版とは言えません。そのためそのバージョン自体に問題がある可能性もあります。

Comment: バージョンや環境による差異が起こるということは、指定されたバージョンでやっていないからではないでしょうか？　まさか動かないものを教材として指定することはないと思いますし、第一それをちゃんと回答者が答えようとした場合、schooに登録して事実関係を確認する必要があるのではないでしょうか。なのであれば、まずは質問者の方が教材を確認してみることをおすすめする、という意味での発言でした。

Comment: DBを作る手順を抜かしている、という断定をしてしまったことは事実かはわかりませんので、誤りでした。